# Difference between asp.net master pages and SharePoint master pages?

Tags: master-page

I am new in sharepoint can anyone suggest Difference between asp.net master pages and SharePoint master pages?

Answer (score 1):

Master Pages were introduced in version 2.0 of ASP.NET. Master Pages are a template that other pages
can inherit from to keep consistent functionality. The pages that inherit from Master Pages are referred to
as content pages. Master Pages allow the ASP.NET developer to keep consistent, reusable, Web-based
code (html, css, javascript, etc.) in one high level place, so the content pages can concentrate on their
specific web-based code. This allows for easily manageable Web-based applications.

SharePoint is designed on the concept of Master Pages. Almost all of the out of the box ASP.NET pages
in SharePoint inherit from a Master Page. Thus, if you want to customize the look and feel of all the
SharePoint pages, you can do this by customizing Master Pages. This allows for a centralized place to
make customizations (instead of modifying every Web page in the entire SharePoint system).

You can go through following link for more information,

http://www.bsb.bw/sites/default/files/ASP%20NET%20Master%20Pages%20and%20SharePoint.pdf

http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2007/05/master-pages-vs-themes-which-do-you-choose/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445711/asp-net-master-page-vs-sharepoint-page-layout-template